# Как настроить вывод числовых значений в Label в десятичном виде?

Tags: swift, типы-данных, числа, label

У меня после расчета на Label выводится число.
Загвоздка в том, что при малых вводных значениях на выходе получается экспоненциальная форма (1.32492е-10 к примеру).
Как можно настроить вывод в десятичном виде (0.0000000000132492)?

**UPD**
Обновил код:

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.locale = Locale.current
        formatter.numberStyle = NumberFormatter.Style.decimal
        formatter.minimumSignificantDigits = 6

        if let text = textField.text, let number = formatter.number(from: text) {

            angstrem = number.doubleValue

            arshinLabel.text = formatter.string(from: NSDecimalNumber(string: textField.text).multiplying(by: 0.00000000014060742))
```

}

Проблема теперь в том, что при вводе числа с запятой (12,325579) он умножает только целую часть...

Comment: Почитайте про Numerformatter.

Comment: @OrestMykha почитал. Попробовал. обновил код в шапке, что из этого вышло

Comment: formatter.roundingMode = NumberFormatter.RoundingMode.halfUp;
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 3